# Put JSON in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a hard time with $.ajax(). I have this HTML page :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="gettr" id="gettr">
         <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="ro">
         <input type="text" name="tickkey" id="tickkey" value="">
         <br>
         <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
         <input type="reset" value="Cancel" onclick="$(&quot;#hereinfo&quot;).html(&quot;&quot;);">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the script :

```
$("#gettr").submit(function() {

    var url = "handler.php"; 

    $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: url,
           dataType: "application/json",
           data: $("#gettr").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data) {
               alert('Done');
           }
         });

    return false; 
});
```

I'm running the script locally now, and my problem is that the script doesn't do anything.When I click on send button it just adds `?lang=ro&tickkey=value_inputed_in_the_form` at the end of the url in the address bar.What should I do so I can store the JSON returned by the server in a variable?

Thank you!

Comment: Is your code waiting the DOM to be loaded?

Comment: Your form missing the `method="GET"` attribute.

Comment: I already have type:"GET" in $.ajax(). Do I need to set it in the HTML too?

Comment: @DannyBejan It does work without the method attribute. But i don't know is it best practice or not but it would be nice to ask it as new question. Looks interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the reason your query variables are appending to url is because you're executing your script before the DOM loads. You should wrap your script within `$(document).ready(function () {  });` handler.

Use `event.preventDefault()` instead of `return false;`. But Why not `return false;` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false)

```
$(document).ready(function () { //Let the DOM be loaded

   $("#gettr").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //Prevent window default behaviour

    var url = "handler.php"; 

    $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: url,
           dataType: "application/json",
           data: $("#gettr").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data) {
               alert(data);               //Alert your json data from server
           }
         });
    });
    //remember remove return false; because you're already preventing default behaviour
});
```

Comment: I have a bit of a problem.The "handler.php" is on another domain and I get this : "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.that_domain.ro/handler.php?lang=ro&tickkey=. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. 

I found this, but I don't know how to modify it so I can use It.Can you help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-w

Comment: @DannyBejan Ofcourse this not possible because of security reason you're making request to other domain instead of your so this is not allow with javasript though. You can work out this with [cURL](http://php.net/curl) php function. Make the call with ajax to your php file where curl lives (this should be in your domain) and then curl will request to other domain. Hope it give some idea. There is also a nice tutorial to exact problem of your [here](http://www.paulund.co.uk/make-cross-domain-ajax-calls-with-jquery-and-php)

Answer (score 4):

Ensure that the DOM is ready and prevent the form submission before executing the AJAX request.

```
var dataFromServer = {};

// Document ready.
$(function() {

    $( '#gettr' ).on( 'submit', function( event ) {

        // Prevent form submission.
        event.preventDefault();            

        // AJAX request.
        var url = 'handler.php'; 
        $.ajax({
           type: 'GET',
           url: url,
           dataType: 'application/json',
           data: $( '#gettr' ).serialize(),
           success: function( data ) {               
                dataFromServer  = data;
           }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: I took everything in the function down so the script is shorter.

Answer (score 4):

Try to call preventDefault();

```
$("#gettr").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
```